# Spark on Kubernetes, mkdirs failed to create abc

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm using spark 3.4.0, trying to run a job on an on-premise Kubernetes cluster. Spark submit fails when creating driver definition, before its pod is spawned. I'm getting the following stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Uploading file /app/libs/job-impl.jar failed...
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.KubernetesUtils$.uploadFileUri(KubernetesUtils.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.KubernetesUtils$.$anonfun$uploadAndTransformFileUris$1(KubernetesUtils.scala:276)
    ... 
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.KubernetesUtils$.uploadAndTransformFileUris(KubernetesUtils.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicDriverFeatureStep.$anonfun$getAdditionalPodSystemProperties$1(BasicDriverFeatureStep.scala:180)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicDriverFeatureStep.getAdditionalPodSystemProperties(BasicDriverFeatureStep.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesDriverBuilder.$anonfun$buildFromFeatures$5(KubernetesDriverBuilder.scala:86)
    ...
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesDriverBuilder.buildFromFeatures(KubernetesDriverBuilder.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.$anonfun$run$5(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.$anonfun$run$5$adapted(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2786)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.start(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1020)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1111)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error uploading file job-impl.jar
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.KubernetesUtils$.uploadFileToHadoopCompatibleFS(KubernetesUtils.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.KubernetesUtils$.uploadFileUri(KubernetesUtils.scala:323)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/opt/spark/work-dir/spark-upload-bbf57e15-694b-424e-9265-0fc1106db92a
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:425)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1064)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:391)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FilterFileSystem.java:376)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.KubernetesUtils$.uploadFileToHadoopCompatibleFS(KubernetesUtils.scala:347)
```

Where directory `/opt/spark/work-dir` is set through the `spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path` property. The directory is created inside my Dockerfile, via

```
RUN mkdir -p /opt/spark/work-dir
...
RUN chown -R myuser:myuser /opt/spark
RUN chmod 777 /opt/spark/work-dir
```

`spark-submit` command displayed in logs:

```
/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java
-cp /app/spark-dist/conf/:/app/spark-dist/jars/*
...
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/app/libs/*
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/app/libs/*
--conf spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=file:///opt/spark/work-dir
--deploy-mode cluster
--master k8s://https://...
--spark.kubernetes.submitInDriver=true
--verbose
/app/libs/job-impl.jar
```

Unfortunately `hadoop-client-api` uses the `java.io.File.mkdir` to create a directory, and it doesn't provide any information why the directory wasn't created.

Any ideas what could be the reason for this exception? Or at least how to debug it? Or maybe what the `spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path` should be set to (docs aren't too specific on this)?